# How to pass non-simple Exoplayer (2.x) a SurfaceView?

Tags: android, exoplayer

I cant use `SimpleExoPlayer`, because I need to a video renderer with certain parameter. I found that I can pass video and audio renderers to the instance of `ExoPlayer`:

```
final ExoPlayer player = ExoPlayerFactory.newInstance( new Renderer[]{videoRenderer, audioRenderer}, trackSelector, loadControl);
```

But `ExoPlayer` doesnt have method `setVideoSurfaceView()`.

How do I pass a `SurfaceView` to a non-simple ExoPlayer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that for this version of ExoPlayer one needs to create an instance of `ExoPlayer.ExoPlayerMessage` using `C.MSG_SET_SURFACE` and pass it to player via method `sendMessage()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can make configuration changes to various ExoPlayer components by passing messages through the ExoPlayer instance. You can send messages to a component using either the `sendMessages` or `blockingSendMessages` methods. In your case, you can set the `Surface` of `videoRenderer` using your `SurfaceView` instance. For example:

```
player.sendMessage(videoRenderer,
                MediaCodecVideoTrackRenderer.MSG_SET_SURFACE,
                surfaceView.getHolder().getSurface());
```

Comment: I also tried to copy this line from examples of previous version ExoPlayer. But parameter `MediaCodecVideoTrackRenderer` is not available, only parameter `MediaCodecVideoRenderer` is available, which does not have message `MSG_SET_SURFACE`. Is there a way to make this parameter available?